# GWT paginated cellTable reload to a specific page

Tags: gwt, pagination, celltable

I have a paginated `cellTable` , how can I reload the paginated `cellTable` and target it to a specific page? For example, I am viewing page 5, I click the reload button and give `pageNo = 5` as a argument and after loading the pagination `cellTable` are still on `page 5`.

Comment: I'm not sure how you created the table and reload it but table.setVisibleRange(pagesize*(pageNo-1), pageSize) may be work

Comment: Hi,i realized that when i was in the second page with pageSize 10 and i have 8 records in the second page , even though i setVisibleRange(10, 17), but it still show me 10 record with extra 2 records having null value

Comment: thanks,response.maybe setPage(5) is better way.

Comment: Yes , it's better to setPage(5) in the server response, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an [AsyncDataProvider](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/view/client/AsyncDataProvider.html) and a [SimplePager](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/SimplePager.html), you can simply:

```
pager.setPage(5);
```